# Can a c++ operator function name be made into a template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I would like to construct boolean operators for a vector of values; things like `operator<`, `operator<=`, `operator==`, etc.

This is so I can have `std::vector<double> values;` and compare all values to something:

```
std::vector<bool> valuesLessThanZero = values < 0.0;
```

I'm able to do this with a `#define`, such as this:

```
#define BOOL_ARRAY_OPER(OP)                                                   \
template <typename T>                                                         \
std::vector<bool> operator OP (const std::vector<T>& vec, const T& value) {   \
    std::vector<bool> results;                                                \
    results.reserve(vec.size());                                              \
    for (const T& result : vec) {                                             \
        results.push_back(result OP value);                                   \
    }                                                                         \
    return results;                                                           \
}

BOOL_ARRAY_OPER(<)
BOOL_ARRAY_OPER(<=)
BOOL_ARRAY_OPER(>)
BOOL_ARRAY_OPER(>=)
BOOL_ARRAY_OPER(==)
BOOL_ARRAY_OPER(!=)
```

Example code [here](https://repl.it/@OnlineCop1/SizzlingPlushRuntimeerror).

I'm wondering whether there's a way to do this purely with templates, without having to `BOOL_ARRAY_OPER()` each of the operators I wish to use?

It fails to compile if I write it as:

```
template <typename T, typename OP>
std::vector<bool> operator OP (const std::vector<T>& vec, const T& value) { ... }
```

with an error such as:

```
main.cpp:22:19: error: conversion function must be a non-static member function
std::vector<bool> operator OP (const std::vector<T>& vec, const T& value) {
                  ^
```

Comment: Do you want to avoid the `BOOL_ARRAY_OPER`? Or just avoid macros entirely?

Comment: You mean `push_back(valuesLessThanZero, values | filtered([](int v){return v<0;}));` with boost?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the macros, if possible, as there might be another operator I've forgotten about (let's say I had `operator<` but forgot `operator<=`). With templates, those would resolve at compile-time. With macros, it will error in some other file, and the library itself would need to be updated to support the new operator.

Answer (score 2):

The usual c++ way of doing this would be something like a transform:

```
std::vector<double> values;
...
std::vector<bool> valuesLessThanZero;
std::transform(values.cbegin(), values.cend(), std::back_inserter(valuesLessThanZero), [] (double value) { return value < 0; });
```

It would, of course, be possible to write

```
std::vector<bool> operator<(std::vector<double> const & values, double value) { ... }
```

that would produce those sorts of results but I would suggest that you seriously think about whether abusing the syntax in the way you are thinking of would actually be of any benefit. Most people would expect that 'values < 0' would produce a single boolean value, not a vector of such values. Plus of course you would also need to provide

```
std::vector<bool> operator <(bool value, std::vector<double> const & values) { ... }
```

if you want to allow the usual order-agnostic semantics, this quickly balloons if you want to prodive all six comparison operators and even more if you need to handle r-value reference cases.

Comment: This is part of a library which converts R syntax to C++. In R, an `ifelse()` statement operates like a ternary `?:` but on an array: `vec2 = ifelse(vec1 < 100, 0, 100)`. That `vec1 < 100` is what I'm trying to emulate in c++, where each element returns a boolean, and I can do further processing at that point.

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ isn't D. You have to declare each operator independently.

You could define a library that declares all six comparison operators and forwards them through to some other function named like `opBinary(f, x, y)` (as in D) - but that would still require declaring all six individually, such that like:

```
template <typename T>
auto operator==(vector<T> const& v, T const& u) -> vector<bool> {
    return opBinary(std::equal_to{}, v, u);
}

// other 5 here
```

Which would be shorter with a macro, but at least the bulk of the functionality would be in `opBinary` and not be a macro?

---

In range-v3, the implementations of these operators become much simpler since:

```
template <typename T>
auto operator==(vector<T> const& v, T const& y) -> vector<bool> {
    return v | views::transform([&](auto const& x){ return x == u; })
             | ranges::to<std::vector>();
}
```

Which maybe would be good enough to even avoid having to reify the `vector` at the end and use directly. Unfortunately we don't have good partial function application really, (can't just write `(== y)` or some such), but if you write short function objects that do the the right thing:

```
v == x
```

could become

```
v | views::transform(equals(x))
```

Which... isn't bad?